# Как исключить повторное срабатываение replaceAll где это не надо?

Tags: java

Вот кусок кода который использую, не могу найти решения, как сделать чтобы все значение которые пишутся (вставляются в моём случае) с новой строки заменялись запятыми, но при этом в случае **двух подряд, или более**     `\\s`  чтобы заменялись только одной запятую, а не двумя или более.

```
    JTextPane chId = new JTextPane();      
    JButton runQ = new JButton("Generate 'SELECT' Query");
    runQ.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            String text = chId.getText().replaceAll("\\s", ",");
            chId.setText(text);
            if (moreThenOne.isSelected()) {
                selectQ.setText("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (" + chId.getText() + ");");
            } else {
                selectQ.setText("SELECT  id FROM table WHERE id = " + chId.getText() + ";");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте +

```
String text = chId.getText().replaceAll("\\s+", ",");
```

Comment: Спасибо! А то я уже в лес пошел путём добавления                                          `.replaceAll(",,", ",");`